# Resolution-associated Settings

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution, unityscript, aspect-ratio

I am beginner with `Unity` and `UnityScript/JavaScript`. What I am trying to do is for now, all the settings in a menu associated with resolution. The settings will be:

```
1). Aspect Ratio
2). Resolution
3). Fullscreen
```

I would like to make some specifications about these 3 options.

`Aspect ratio:` this settings will allow the player to choose from a list of preset aspect ratios. Also it will have an option called "auto", which will get the screen aspect ratio.

`Resolution:` This is the most popular setting in all games. I will allow the players to choose preset resolutions **of the aspect ratio they have selected above**. For example if the player has selected 16:9 aspect ratio, only resolutions which have this particular ratio will be availabe. If the player has "auto" selected in the aspect ratio option selected, only the resolutions with the aspect ratio detected from the screen will be available to choose from. Also there will be an "auto" option here too, which will detect the screen native resolution and use that one.

`Fullscreen:` This is the easiest of all three. Its basically a switch between playing in fullscreen or windowed mode.

If anyone can help me implement these settings in UnityScript, please post the answer here.